# Javascript time calculating from yesterday to tomorrow

Tags: javascript, time

So let me explain. I'm working on a site where people keep log on how long they were doing something. The problem is when someone is doing something from let's say 23:00 to 2:00. The script I have now says it's -21hours.

The second problem is it calculates minutes in decimals. For example 1:15 is 1,25. This isn't really a big problem but my secondary question is can I get results in minutes?

For my primary question, how can I set a condition if from one day to another calculate 24-$result else calculate normally?

This is what I have now:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#check").click(function() {
           var start = $(".preveri_ure").val();
           var end = $(".preveri_ure_2").val();
           s = start.split(':');
           e = end.split(':');
           min = e[1]-s[1];
           hour_carry = 0;
           if(min < 0){
               min += 60;
               hour_carry += 1;
           }
           hour = e[0]-s[0]-hour_carry;
           min = ((min/60)*100).toString()
           diff = hour + "," + min.substring(0,2);
            $("#show").text("Task lasted for : " + diff + "hours");
    });
```

EDIT:

Start and End hours are inputted by users in an input field with this format: 
Start: 7:00
End 20:15

Also time difference is always less than 24 hours. So date isn't required.

Comment: It looks like the `start` and `end` values are inputted by the user. What kind of input elements are you using?  If you are just collecting the time, that's your problem. You need to collect a full date.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention Start and End hours are inputted by users in an input field with this format: Start: 7:00 End 20:15

I've editted my question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you'll need to change that so that a complete date is inputted. You can use `input type=date` for that.

Comment: Can it be more then a 24 hours diff that you want ? how can you tell if there is not date? Or is it always less then 24 hours

Comment: @O_Z it's always less than 24 hours. It's more for let's say 30 min to 1-2 hour tasks. Maximum of 6 hours on record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely agree with @Scott Marcus. it's easier for comparison if there is full date instead of just hour and Minute.

But from @Studio DnB perspective,
let's consider Start and End time belong to same day. but, start time must be smaller than end time in drop-down selection.

here is code

```
var tempStartDate = new Date(); // just inintialise start and end date
var tempEndtDate = new Date();      
s = date1.split(':');
e = date2.split(':');
tempStartDate.setHours(s[0], s[1], 0); // set Hours and Minutes for start and end date
tempEndtDate.setHours(e[0], e[1], 0);

var startTime ;
var endTime ;
  // compare to make start time less then end time always for same day log
if (tempEndtDate.getTime() > tempStartDate.getTime()){
      endTime = tempEndtDate.getTime();
      startTime= tempStartDate.getTime();
  }
else {
      endTime = tempStartDate.getTime();
     startTime= tempEndtDate.getTime();
 }

  var difference = endTime - startTime;

  var hoursDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60);
    difference -= hoursDifference*1000*60*60

    var minutesDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60);
    difference -= minutesDifference*1000*60
```

Example is on https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/32377/

Comment: Wow Great !!! . you can use function without parameter and pass value of your drop-down into variables. happy coding. thanks

Comment: Almost thought this works but still for start time 23:00 and end time 02:00 it says 21 hours

Comment: I need a condition - if time 1 is bigger than time 2 than use this math: 24 - difference. So for 23:00 to 2:00 the math should be 24-(23-2). Actually I think this is the right condition: if (tempEndtDate.getTime() > tempStartDate.getTime()){
So if I use the math there could it work? But then I'd need to put the hoursDifference in else statement?

Comment: @StudioDnB if you passed 23:00 as start time and 2:00 as finished time then it won't be wrong selection ??  it will change whole day after 23:59. isn't it ?

Comment: task can be started at any time. PHP only saves date of the end time. So it logs when the task was finished. It's required so because of the daily statistics.

Comment: @StudioDnB please have a look to this https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/32379/
I have added 1 whole date if end time  is less than start time. just consider next day by setting enddate

Comment: this works perfectly. I did the thing I was talking about in the upper comments but it didn't work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If the first time hours is bigger then the second, add to the second 24 hours.

An event better solution is to create from each a JavaScript Date object and subtract.

Comment: What if it's been more than a full day? Your suggestion would lose a day or more if that's the case.

Comment: @ScottMarcus If it's more then a full day and all he has is the time there is nothing to do. I assume it's never more then a day.Read his question again and see that this is true.Please remove down vote

Comment: @ScottMarcus From his question it's never more then a full day.

Comment: @ScottMarcus since he stated it's less then 24 always will your remove your down vote ?

Answer (score 0):

I would require the user to enter date and time and use Javascript UTC that converts the specific dateTime to seconds since January 1 1970. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp
Then calculate startDate - endDate and convert to minutes.